# Meteor error: not be able to set environment variables

Tags: meteor, environment, setting

Meteor.startup(function () {
    // code to run on server at startup

```
console.log('Setting environment variables')
process.env.MONGO_URL= 'mongodb://localhost:27017/dbName';
console.log(process.env) // MONGO_URL inside process.env is showing that variable is setup  but its not working.
```

})

Comment: You want to deploy it on your own mongoDB? Is it DEV or PROD?

Answer (score 0):

`MONGO_URL` is unfortunately one of those variables, which need to be set before startup. If you're trying to start a development process you will need to do something like this:

```
METEOR_URL=mongodb://localhost:27017/dbName meteor
```

If you're trying to deploy your app on some custom production setup, then the answer depends on the particular solution you're planning to use. If this is something standard, then the service provider would usually have a simple web tool where you can configure environment variables for your app process. This is basically were you should look for.

If this some home-brewed-solution then there are a lot of possible answers. The thing to keep in mind is that you should provide the custom `MONGO_URL` variable to environment before starting your meteor process.